# Why after this method the result is different in Java and PHP and how to fix it?

Tags: java, php, bit-shift

With smaller numbers, this method works correctly in Java and Python, but with larger numbers, the result is different. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Java code:

```
private static int combine(int val1, int val2) {
    int val3 = val1 << 8;
    return (val3 & 0xFFFFFFF) + val2 ^ (-0x10000000 & val3) >>> 24;
}
```

PHP code:

```
 function combine($val1, $val2) {
    $val3 = $val1 << 8;
    return ($val3 & 0xFFFFFFF) + $val2 ^ uRShift((-0x10000000 & $val3), 24);
 }
 
 function uRShift($a, $b) {
    if ($a < 0) 
    { 
        $a = ($a >> 1); 
        $a &= 2147483647; 
        $a |= 0x40000000; 
        $a = ($a >> ($b - 1)); 
    } else { 
        $a = ($a >> $b); 
    } 
    return $a; 
 }
```

For example, if in both methods I insert these numbers `combine(125,107)`, the result in Java and PHP will be the same (32107). If I put in a larger number, like `combine(287651245, 107)`, the result for Java is 87403851 and for PHP it is 87407691. I suspect there is something wrong with the left shifting.

Comment: For the second combine I get 3521611 in PHP, not 87407691. See: https://3v4l.org/08Pvc

Comment: Your Java code uses `0xFFFFFFF` (seven F’s) while your PHP code uses `0xFFFFFF` (six F’s).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware oops my bad maybe I accidently deleted one 'F' while writing the question.

Comment: @VGR thanks for pointing it out It was just a mistake in the question. I edited my question. I'm running my PHP on 7.2.24

Comment: Your uRShift function seems strange.  I would suggest using the formula given in [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):  “The value of *n* >>> *s* is *n* right-shifted *s* bit positions with zero-extension, where: • If *n* is positive, then the result is the same as that of *n* >> *s*. • If *n* is negative and the type of the left-hand operand is `int`, then the result is equal to that of the expression (*n* >> *s*) + (2 << ~s).”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today most of PHP releases are x64 builds, that means integers are 64-bit long, so the result of this arithmetic `$val3 = $val1 << 8;` is a 64-bit integer.

In Java you forced the result to be a signed 32-bit integer `int`, the left shift operator automatically cut off the exceeded bits, but in PHP it won't, so you need do it manually.

```
function toSignedInt($a) {
    if(PHP_INT_SIZE == 4) return $a;
    $a &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return $a > 2147483647 ? $a - 4294967296 : $a;
}
```

You need be carefull in every places of overflow and wrap them with this function. In this code, they are the left shift operator and the add operator.

```
function combine($val1, $val2) {
   $val3 = toSignedInt($val1 << 8);
   return toSignedInt(($val3 & 0xFFFFFFF) + $val2)
          ^ uRShift((-0x10000000 & $val3), 24);
}
```